# Add user before running custom action in Wix

Tags: windows, installation, wix, windows-installer

We have an install script in Wix, which contains Fragments, components and some custom actions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension' >
    <Product Id="*" Name="Installation" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine">
        </Package>

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="cab1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MyInstallation" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="MyComponents" />
        </Feature>
        <util:Group Id="Users" Name="Users"/>

        <CustomAction Id="InstallMyService"
                      Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"
                      ExeCommand="[INSTALLFOLDER]bin\my-service.bat install"
                      Execute="deferred"
                      Impersonate="no"
                      Return="check"/>

        <CustomAction Id="SetEnvironmentVariable" BinaryKey="ActionLib" DllEntry="SetEnvironmentVariableForNewUser" />
        <Binary Id='ActionLib' SourceFile='..\InstallerActionLibrary\bin\Release\InstallerActionLibrary.CA.dll' />

        <CustomAction Id="StartMyService"
                      Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"
                      ExeCommand="[INSTALLFOLDER]bin\my-service.bat start"              
                      Execute="deferred"
                      Impersonate="no"
                      Return="asyncWait"/>

        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="InstallMyService" After="InstallFiles"/>
            <Custom Action="SetEnvironmentVariable" After="InstallMyService"/>
            <Custom Action="StartMyService" After="SetEnvironmentVariable"/>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
                <Directory Id="Company" Name="Company">
                      <Directory Id="App" Name="Product">
                            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Service" />
                      </Directory>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Component Id="NewUser" Guid="{12345678-ABCD-1234-ABCD-987654321FED}">
                <CreateFolder />
                    <util:User Id="CIUSER" CreateUser="yes" UpdateIfExists="no" Name="SERVICEUSER" PasswordNeverExpires="yes" Password="********">
                    <util:GroupRef Id="Users" />
                </util:User>
            </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

However, one of the Custom Actions, `SetEnvironmentVariable`, needs to be run after the user has been set up, in the fragment at the bottom of the file.  And this does not happen.  `SetEnvironmentVariable` fails because it cannot find the user.

The sequence, given in `InstallExecuteSequence` begins after `InstallFiles` has occurred.  I have tried to find a more appropriate place to start the sequence, using the list given [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372038(v=vs.85).aspx).  I have tried `PublishProduct` and the result is the same.

Is there any way to get the user added before the custom action runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion from @zett42 was a good one.  However, it still did not solve the problem.

The solution was the incorrect use of `Execute="deferred"`. The execution of all the custom actions should have been set as:

```
Execute="commit"
```

From the [Wix Documentation:](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/customaction.html)

**commit**

Indicates that the custom action will run after successful completion of the installation script (at the end of the installation).

Changed the Execute type to commit and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have no direct answer, but one that should help you to figure it out by yourself:

1. Open the MSI package using a tool like Orca (included in Win SDK) or [InstEd](http://www.instedit.com/) (my personal preference).
2. Navigate to the `InstallExecuteSequence` table.
3. Lookup the record of the WiX custom action that creates the user and copy the `Action` identifier of that record.
4. Use that identifier for the `After` attribute of the element `<Custom Action="SetEnvironmentVariable"/>`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I found the correct Action, but it did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @zett42.
There are some wix standard actions which should be checked in msi editor, 
if you need to know when exactly they are being called. We normally don`t get much documentation for such actions.

Check if your msi has SchedSecureObjects_x64 or SchedSecureObjects custom action in msi. Schedule SetEnvironmentVariable custom action after that action.